# Is there any way to automatically set outgoing email address based on recipient's email or domain in mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I'd like mail to be automatically be sent from an account based on domain the domain of the recipient.

Details:

I've set up multiple email accounts in mail.app, both personal and work.  I find myself frequently annoyed, because I forget to set the "from" address, and thus email work from my personal account.  What I'd like to have happen, is if the email recipient is boss@serious.biz, then use my account with derek@serious.biz, otherwise use derek@clownpants.com, or something to that effect.

[A related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52865/controlling-which-address-my-outgoing-mail-is-seen-to-be-from), but in my case I'd like it to be dependent on the recipient.

MBP late 2011, OSX 10.7.4

Comment: As an update, it looks like the answer is no.  I've looked at applescript and it doesn't look like there is any sort of hook in that would work for this, someone please chime in if this is wrong.

Comment: Darn, I had literally the exact same question. Are there any email apps at all that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this in Apple Mail. It only works for messages which you are replying to (they automatically use the same outgoing address which received the original message). There is no hook in AppleScript, nor an option in Automator by which to make this happen. If it were possible, as of right now, it would still require a third-party plugin, which I have not been able to find either. So unfortunately, the answer is now.

Note: Also, if you select the inbox of the account from which you want to send the message, then compose, Mail will automatically use that account's email address for sending, unless you change it. Not quite as helpful as what you were hoping for, but at least something worth considering.

Good luck and happy mailing!

Comment: Thanks for checking Automater (something I didn't know about) and confirming my suspicion.

Comment: You're quite welcome.